# how to get range of inactive sheets in excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel

In Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet, I want to get the range of inactive sheet, is there any way to create the new object of the inactive sheet? I can get the range of the active sheet by using Excel.Application.ActiveSheet.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple approach to this :

```
var wb = Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
List<Worksheet> sheets = new List<Worksheet();
foreach(var sheet in wb.Sheets)
{
   if(sheet != Excel.Application.ActiveSheet)
   {
        sheets.add(sheet);
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems that I only need to use application.getrange and it works.